# How to access a webelement in other class in POM - Selenium

Tags: selenium, pom.xml

I have 2 pages (landing page and registration page). In landing page, I am storing webelements using @FindBy annotations. I need to use the Webelements oflanding page in the registration page. How can I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create an object of the class and access it like variable

Suppose class A having @FindBy function and variable is suppose myelement

Then use (it is Java, try similar in whatever lang you are using):

```
A aobject= new A();
A.myelement;
```